# Batch updates in JPA (Toplink)

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, toplink

Is there any way if executing batch updates (EntityManager persist() or merge()) using JPA Toplink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a batch update, you can create a Query (either JPQL or Native SQL) that performs the update using the EntityManager, and then call [executeUpdate](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) on that query.

Comment: If I use JPQL (using XML file), I usually get an error about the fields unitialized or unknown (some error like that). How can I cope up with such error?
I wish to avoid using query in code, as I may need to change the code often then.

Comment: Can you post the query, the error, and the associated entities?